# java / android: table layout - visibility of specific column

Tags: java, android, tablelayout

i dynamically created a table layout.
Now i want to change the visibility of spezific columns if the screen is landscape or portrait.
Is this possible with my code?

Thanks for helping.

```
  for (Element row : rows) {

                TableRow eins = new TableRow(this);
                Elements cells=row.select("td");
                for (Element cell : cells) {
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    if (cell.select("img").size() > 0) {
                    tv.setText("A ");
                    }
                    else {
                    tv.setText(" " + cell.text() + " ");
                    }
                    if (tv.length() < 9) {
                        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                    }
                    eins.addView(tv);
                }           
                tbl.addView(eins);
            }
```

if operator for orientattion

```
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    // In landscape
} else {
    // In portrait
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it myself.

```
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                tbl.setColumnCollapsed(0, true);
                // In landscape

            } else {
                tbl.setColumnCollapsed(0, true);
                tbl.setColumnCollapsed(4, true);
                tbl.setColumnCollapsed(5, true);
                tbl.setColumnCollapsed(6, true);
                tbl.setColumnCollapsed(7, true);
                // In portrait
```